# Blender is not launching as the image attached

Tags: python

[image]

Works fine till yesterday. Help. I'm on RTX2060 16gb ram and latest drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the third line, you have plugins that are trying to connect to the internet and having trouble making the connection. The SCATTERS plugin looks to be trying to update itself. I'd guess it can't connect, and if the developer didn't put in an error check on that update process, the script would just keep trying to find that connection and hang in a loop and keep Blender from launching.

Check your internet or firewall, if those are fine try disabling plugins.